# how do tell with an if statement if there this index exists in a list or not?

Tags: python

```
for j in range(1, minimum):
    v=minimum/j
    if (v).is_integer()==True:
        llist.append(v)
        llist.append(j)
    else:
        pass
    if llist(j)==True:
        indexmin=llist(j)
        listofmulmin.append(minimum*indexmin)
    else:
        pass
```

this is not my full code

Comment: Can you please use the formatting tools to format this as a code block?

Comment: It's very difficult to tell what you are looking for, and the code block you have is confusing.  For example, you have an object `llist` that appears to be a list, but then you attempt this line: `if llist(j) == True:`.  If `llist` is, in fact, a list then you'll get a `TypeError` here.

Comment: Select your code and press Control+K/Command+K

Comment: And tell us where you want the list to be checked?

Comment: i am trying to tell whether this list has that index or not

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you trying to figure out if `j` is in `llist`?

Comment: I don't see a reasons for the `else: pass` statements - what is their purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Since list indexes go from (0, .., n-1), you can easily check a potential index by comparing it to the total size of the list. Here is an example 3 element list test

```
llist = [1,2,3]
for i in range(5):
    if i >= 0 and len(llist) > i:
        print('{} is a valid index'.format(i))
    else:
        print('{} is not a valid index'.format(i))
```

that produces

```
0 is a valid index
1 is a valid index
2 is a valid index
3 is not a valid index
4 is not a valid index
```

Comment: but then how do i tell whether this list has it or not? becuase you did a greater than symbol

Comment: `len(llist) > i` is `True` only when `i` is less than the length... if `i` is less than the length of the list, then it is a valid index. I notice that I didn't account for indexes less than zero, so in your code you may want to replace `if llist(j)==True:` with `if j >= 0 and len(llist) > j and llist[j] == True:` (I'm not sure what you intended for that last compare though).

Comment: Did you want to check whether `j` is a valid index of `llist` or if `j` is in `llist`? That second thing would be `if j in llist:`. You asked about the list index so I'm not sure what you want.